# Multiprocessing beautifulsoup4 function to increase performance

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing

As is:
I built a function that takes an url as argument, scrapes the page and puts the parsed info into a list. Next to this, I have a list of the urls and I'm mapping the list of urls to the url parser function and iterating through each url. The issue is that I have around 7000-8000 links so parsing iteratively takes a lot of time. This is the current iterative solution:

```
mapped_parse_links = map(parse, my_new_list)
all_parsed = list(it.chain.from_iterable(mapped_parse_links))
```

'parse' is the scraper function and 'my_new_list' is the list of URLs.

To be:
I want to implement multiprocessing so that instead of iterating through the list of URLs, it would utilize multiple CPUs to pick up more links at the same time and parse the info using the parse function. I tried the following:

```
import multiprocessing
with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
    mapped_parse_links = p.map(parse, my_new_list)
    all_parsed = list(it.chain.from_iterable(mapped_parse_links))
```

I tried different solutions using the Pool function as well, however all of the solutions run for eternity. Can someone give me pointers on how to solve this? 
Thanks.

Comment: You're facing with IO-bound tasks but `multiprocessing` is preferred for CPU-bound tasks. In IO context `asyncio` and `threading` could really outperform multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

Taken, with minor alterations, from the [docs for concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html):

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            url = future_to_url[future]
            try:
                data = future.result()
                # Do something with the scraped data here
            except Exception as exc:
                print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
```

You will have to substitute your parse function in for load_url.

Comment: I tweeked the code a bit by adding global variable data = [] and data.append(future.result()) so that data contains a list of all info scraped from the websites. However, now the scraping is even slower than it was with the iterative approach

Comment: Depending on whether or not your program is CPU bound, it may be better to use `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor`.  You can also tweak the max_workers and chunksize options.

Comment: I ended up using multiprocessing package as the bottleneck was a CPU-bound issue (the parsing). I used `if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(cpu_count() * 2) as p:
     try:
      df = pd.DataFrame(p.map(parse, my_new_list))
     except Exception as exc: 
      print('%r generated an exception: %s' % exc)`. The only weird thing is, that this code wasn't working on windows os but worked on linux vm.. does someone know why?